# Indice compuesto por varios campos C# Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

estoy trabajando con c# Entity Framework code first, creando una tabla me doy cuenta que necesitaré más de una clave como debería hacerlo ? perdón la consulta pero soy nuevo en esto, muchas gracias

```
public class Cae
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumInicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumFinal { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CAETipoCFE  { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CAEFechaVencimiento { get; set; }
    public int? CAEEspecial { get; set; }
    public int? CAECausalTipoDelCae { get; set; }
    public bool CAEFinalizado { get; set; }

}

public class Empresa
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NombreComercial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(12)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Rut { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string ResolucionIva { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Sucursal> Sucursales { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Sobre> Sobres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Cae> Caes  { get; set; }

}
```

El id es mi clave primaria y necesitaría que Empresa,CAETipoCFE, CAENumero fueran un indice único ya que no debería repetirse.
Cuando genero la propiedad de navegación (public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }), esta me crea en la Tabla Caes un campo Empresa_Id, el cuál me gustaría que fuese parte de este indice para no tener que crear otra propiedad en mi modelo para luego armar dicho indice.

---

```
public class Cae
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long Empresa_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CAETipoCFE { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public long CAENumero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumInicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumFinal { get; set; }
    [Required]
   
    public DateTime CAEFechaVencimiento { get; set; }
    public int? CAEEspecial { get; set; }
    public int? CAECausalTipoDelCae { get; set; }
    public bool CAEFinalizado { get; set; }

}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cae>().HasIndex(c => c.Empresa_Id);
    }

public partial class AddIndexEmpresaID : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id", "dbo.Empresas");
        DropIndex("dbo.Caes", new[] { "Empresa_Id" });
        AddColumn("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id1", c => c.Long());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id1");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id1", "dbo.Empresas", "Id");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id1", "dbo.Empresas");
        DropIndex("dbo.Caes", new[] { "Empresa_Id1" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Caes", new[] { "Empresa_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id1");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Caes", "Empresa_Id", "dbo.Empresas", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

}

[image: SQL]

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes crear es una `constraint` usando el atributo  `[Index]` aunque tambien lo podrias configurar mediente `fluent`

[Configuring an Index on one or more properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN#configuring-an-index-on-one-or-more-properties)

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<Cae>() 
    .Property(t => t.Empresa) 
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("Index_Empresa_CAETipoCFE_CAENumero", 1) { IsUnique = true }))
    
    .Property(t => t.CAETipoCFE) 
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("Index_Empresa_CAETipoCFE_CAENumero", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
            
    .Property(t => t.CAENumero) 
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(
            new IndexAttribute("Index_Empresa_CAETipoCFE_CAENumero", 3) { IsUnique = true }));
```

La idea es que todas las propiedades definan el mismo nombre del indice, asignandole a cada propiedad un orden

[Setting unique Constraint with fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573550/setting-unique-constraint-with-fluent-api)

[Is it possible to set a unique constraint using Entity Framework Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837800/is-it-possible-to-set-a-unique-constraint-using-entity-framework-code-first)

Si usas `EF 6.2` podria ser que dispongas de la propiedad `HasIndex()`

[How to create index in Entity Framework 6.2 with code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618237/how-to-create-index-in-entity-framework-6-2-with-code-first)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cae>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Empresa, p.CAETipoCFE, p.CAENumero })
    .IsUnique();
```

Si usas `EF Core` puedes aplicar el `HasAlternateKey`

[The Fluent API HasAlternateKey Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasalternatekey-method)

Comment: Actualicé un poco la pregunta en base a tu respuesta, tu sabes que al utilizar la opcion:       modelBuilder.Entity<Cae>()
                 .HasIndex(p => new { p.Empresa, p.CAETipoCFE, p.CAENumero })
    .             IsUnique(); con api fluent tengo error ya que p.empresa esuna propiedad de navegación. Ya que dicha propiedad según el modelo Cae me genera en la tabla un campo Empresa_Id, te consulto si es posible usar ese campo para armar el índice ? Mil Gracias

Comment: Tienes que tener la propiedad simples para la empresa, como ser `EmpresaId` para crear la relacion, es esa propiedad la que debes usar con el `HasIndex`. Si dejas que el modelo cree esa propiedad sola no podras usarla, tienes que definirla y mapearla

Comment: Y eso no me genera en la tabla duplicidad en estos dos campos?, como hago entonces para que la propiedad de navegación siga estando y no me cree el campo? Me podrás dar un ejemplo si no es mucha molestia? Mil gracias

Comment: Si creas una propiedad de nombre `Empresa_Id` mapeara con ese mismo nombre, el tema es que tienes que definir la propiedad para poder usarla en el maping del indice. Dejas ambas propiedades la de navegacion y la del Id de la empresa. Cuando defines la relacion tienes que indicar que use esa propiedad, en el fluent mapping

Comment: Me pasa esto al hacer el hasIndex modelBuilder.Entity<Cae>().HasIndex(c => c.Empresa_Id);             lo que me hace es generarme el campo que generaba antes pero le cambia el nombre ahora y le pone Empresa_Id1". Agrego a la pregunta el código para que puedas ver bien lo que hace. Muchas gracias por todo y perdón por robar tu tiempo

Comment: Pero donde indicas que `Empresa_Id` y `Empresa` trabajan juntos ? tienes que definir por fluent la navegacion

Comment: Gracias Genio!!!!!!!!!!!!! me diste tremenda ayuda !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar utilizando llave primaria compuesta, pero te va a resultar complicado mantener tu base de datos, lo recomendable es que sea única. No quiero entrar en detalles conceptuales, pero que tenga más de una llave primaria podría significar que tu diseño de base de datos está mal. Para realizarlo en código sería de la siguiente manera:

> TABLA 1

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClaveId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Clave2Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Si tu llave primaria tiene que ver con referencias a otra(s) llave(s) primaria de otra(s) tabla(s) lo mejor sería que uses una llave foránea. En código c# sería algo así:

> TABLA 2

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int Tabla2Id { get; set; }

public string Tabla2Nombre { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ClaveId")]// hace referencia a la tabla 1
public int ClaveId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, bastó con nombrar los campos indíce en lugar de Id solamente, nombrerlos como EmpresaId o CaeId y poner las propiedades de navegación en su lugar para luego crear el índice compuesto que necesitaba.

Dejo las clases para que vean como solucioné.

```
public class Empresa
{
    public long EmpresaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NombreComercial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(12)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Rut { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public string ResolucionIva { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Sucursal> Sucursales { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Sobre> Sobres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Cae> Caes  { get; set; }

}
```

public class Cae
{
public long CaeId { get; set; }

```
    [Required]        
    public int CAETipoCFE { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public long CAENumero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumInicial { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CAENumFinal { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CAEFechaVencimiento { get; set; }
    public int? CAEEspecial { get; set; }
    public int? CAECausalTipoDelCae { get; set; }
    public bool CAEFinalizado { get; set; }

    public long EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cae>()
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.EmpresaId, p.CAETipoCFE, p.CAENumero })
            .IsUnique();
    }
```